# Webscraping and page interaction in android

Tags: android, selenium, kotlin, web-scraping

How would I go about interacting with web pages in android? I have previously used python and selenium on PC for this purpose, unsure how things work in android.
I've checked out selendroid but it hasn't been updated for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wrapper around Selenium, called [Appium](https://appium.io/), which can be used to implement Selenium tests on Android and/or iOS. You can continue using python and write tests in a very similar way.